# Python Requests really slow when opening multiple tabs at the same time

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a python automation program to post some content in a enterprise social media using their API. I have to use this program to every customer I have, so I open the python program multiple times and just pass the login/pass to each tab.

For some reason as more tabs I open, more python requests get slower. I have hardware and internet connection to open more than 800 times this program, but if I open more than 30 - 40, all requests start getting REALLY slow (only requests, all other steps on the program works in normal speed) in a point I start get "Max retries exceeded" error trying to connect to the endpoint.

**That's not** a limit from the host (this problem happens to every host my program need to call, even my own API). I have already tried open 50 instances in a VM and it starts gets really slow and at the same time I open just a single instance in my original SO and performs perfectly with no lag (meanwhile every python program in VM is getting stuck on requests).

Requests example:

```
    url = f'http://myendpoint.app/api/v1'

    body = {
        "id": id,
        "action": "notifications"
    }

    x = requests.get(url, json=body, timeout=15)
    print(x.text)
    return json.loads(x.text)
```

I have already tried using Proxy, different computers in different addresses, using requests session and no lucky. Asking here is my last resource.

Comment: would be better if you could have complete minimal example code that shows the problem.  No one is going to be able to give you much more than a guess as you have it described.

Comment: @LhasaDad that's the problem, I don't have too much else than that. All requests I make is extremely simple, just passing some data on body and checking for response. I really don't know what else can I show to help figure this out.

Comment: Your question lacks details. What does REALLY slow mean? How exactly is speed measured? By the way requests module does not have "tabs".

Comment: you don't have to use json module (last line can be just `return x.json()`)

Comment: How big is the response? If it is, then it might be a CPU issue because you spend CPU resources to print and decode the response (`.loads()`)

Comment: @SrMilton I understand,  but if you can post code (maybe do something with threads or subprocesses in a loop that gets a bunch of requests running at the same time) its easier for someone to grab it and work with it to help figure out what might be going on and respond.   If your going to ask them to write code (which might not even match what you are experiencing), you are going to get few responses.   Just giving you the reality of when and how folks will respond.

Comment: Just to update here: The problem was something related to request sessions. When I figured this out I just removed sessions from my program and I was manually storing and sending cookies I need each request. This solved my problem.